# KendoUI: exact time rendering in scheduler

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, radscheduler

I know that RadScheduler (also Telerik) has an option 'Exact time rendering' (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/exacttimerendering/defaultcs.aspx) but does this also exist in KendoUI Scheduler ?
Have been searching the documentation but was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called [snap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#configuration-snap) in the Kendo UI Scheduler. Here is a live demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/move-resize.html (try unchecking the checkbox)

Comment: Not entirely correct. Snap makes the items snap to the boundaries of the time grid, but the demo does do exact time rendering.
As for the snap function itself, i find it a bit buggy. When i change the time of an item to f.i. 12.16, turn on the snap function and move it, it snaps to xx.16 or xx.46 instead of the bounderies.